# Which fruit is this seedling from?

Tags: identification, fruit-trees, seedlings

A couple of weeks ago I planted some seeds of different fruits that I ate. 
Some didn't make it and some did, however, I lost track on this one and don't remember what this plant is.

Here are some pictures.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you remember the list of the options (which fruits you ate)?

Comment: Pear, Apple, papaya, kiwi & mango

Comment: Those are the ones I planted. The kiwi died first then the apple

Comment: Its not Mango and Papaya for sure.

Comment: And I can exclude apple and pear.

Comment: Why definitely not part or papaya?

Comment: The leaf shape is not right for either a papaya or a pear, for one thing. Your plant doesn't look like a young tree - it looks more vine-like, which makes me think kiwi is the most likely of the ones you listed. I only have experience with hardy kiwi, and those do not have shiny leaves like these, so I'm not certain. Are you certain there aren't any other possibilities?

Comment: Since when I took this picture it has sprouted more bud like stuff. I'll send updated pix tonight

Comment: Now that you're mentioned hardy kiwi I did plant seeds from different kiwis could possibly be that but I'll wait to see what you think about the new pix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a kiwi.

Unfortunately, the best matching picture I can find can't be linked to or copied.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not one of the ones you listed, but I really don't think it's any of those, to be quite honest. It looks just like an indoor pepper to me (Capsicum annuum), and probably a sweet bell pepper, at that. The leaves are kind of curling, though. I grew peppers this last fall/winter/spring that looked like that (sans the downward curling). They're outside, now.

Here are some pictures that look pretty close (these aren't mine, though; note that they're both of indoor peppers, and not outdoor ones):

- [Picture 1](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_i_SbVEomlrk/SVBQmj3b8BI/AAAAAAAAE_M/gQHjMU422rk/s1600-h/pretzels+020.JPG)
- [Picture 2](http://www.passingtherelish.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/indoor-pepper-plant.jpg)